# Programmatically access iPhone System Setting

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to access and/or set general iPhone system settings like "WiFi On/Off" etc?

Comment: You should consider the fact people using your app are going to be pissed if you turn off their WiFi.

Comment: Noted - but I would only be turning it on and with permission.

Answer (score 0):

Only through the private API for most settings.  Some are exposed through private API (check out [Stumbler](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/) which uses private API.  Please note that using the private API bars the app from being on the App Store.

Comment: But i want to know which api it is using,