# Where to find the official list with data that is not available for being used inside the application?

Tags: ios, apple-documentation

I'm looking for an official Apple documentation where I can see what data I can't or can use/access from inside my application. Spend a couple of days on a different resources, but didn't find any valuable information directly from Apple.

Usually people say that Apple restricts the application from accessing the private information etc. But nothing more special. Is there are any place where I can find all of that restrictions written officially by Apple?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easy to find when searching for protected resources, here describes what areas and what keys are needed:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/protected_resources

Comment: Thanks @PabloSierra! That will help. But I'm also looking for some information about the System Settings. For example I want to be able to check if the call forwarding is turned on. Or do you mean that I have to perceive this protected resources as the only available resources?

Comment: based on the last threads doesn't look possible to read the system settings from the public APIs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150321/programmatically-access-iphone-system-setting

What you can check is if the phone has some capabilities